# texlive font problem

Tags: fonts, bold, italic

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and TeX Live 2022.
After that, bold and italic \bf \em don't work.
Moreover, chapter and section titles are set in default font without bold.
I purged and re-installed Tex Live but the problem still persists.
Anyone has any idea how to fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: `\bf` has been deprecated for about 30 years; `\em` is not meant for italic, but for “emphasis”, and it shouldn’t generally appear in documents. Can you please show an example of “failing” code?

Comment: \textbf, \chapter, \section, \subsection all don't work. They are not rendered in bold font.

Comment: I found the reason: Adding \usepackage{CJKutf8} causes the bold and italic fonts of English text to be wrongly rendered. Removing \usepackage{CJKutf8} resolves the problem.